# Node js post data is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, post

This is in my `app.js` file...

```
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var reg = require('./routes/register');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: true
})); 

...
...
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);
app.get('/register', reg.register);

app.post('/signup', reg.postRegister);
```

In my `register.js` file I am rendering a new page using the `get`, and I am trying to access `post` data from that page using the `post` function...

```
exports.register = function (req, res){
    res.render('register.jade', { title: 'register' });
}

exports.postRegister = function (req, res) {
     console.log(req.body.reg_name);
}
```

The `get` works, and the `post` function is called but the console logs `undefined`, I cannot figure out why. This is my html file that `register.js` is trying to access...

```
form(name="login", method="post", action='/signup', enctype="multipart/form-data")
    div.personal
        span.label name
        input(type="text", name="reg_name")
        input(type="submit", value="Submit")
```

Why am I getting `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this attribute [enctype="multipart/form-data"]